# How to Compare CSV Column using awk?

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, csv, awk

I receive and CSV like this:

```
column$1,column$2,column$
john,P,10
john,P,10
john,A,20
john,T,30
john,T,10
marc,P,10
marc,C,10
marc,C,20
marc,T,30
marc,A,10
```

I need so sum the values and display the name and results but column$2 needs to show the sum of values T separated from values P,A,C.
Output should be this:

```
column$1,column$2,column$3,column$4
john,PCA,40
john,T,40,CORRECT
marc,PCA,50
marc,T,30,INCORRECT
```

All i could do was extract the columns i need from the original csv:

```
    awk -F "|" '{print $8 "|" $9 "|" $4}' input.csv >> output.csv
```

Also sort by the correct column:

```
sort -t "|" -k1 input.csv >> output.csv
```

And add a new column to the end of the csv:

```
awk -F, '{NF=2}1' OFS="|" input.csv >> output.csv
```

I managed to sum and display the sum by column$1 and $2, but i don't how to group different values from column$2:

```
awk -F "," '{col[$1,$2]++} END {for(i in col) print i, col[i]}' file > output
```

Comment: try `awk '{if($2 == "T") $4 = "MATCHED" ; print $0}' file > newFile` Good luck.

Comment: Post some concise, testable sample input and expected output and we can help you.

Comment: just edited the question

Comment: What determines whether the text `,CORRECT` or `,INCORRECT` should be appended to the line? It's in your example output, but there's no explanation for it in your question.

Comment: Sorry. If the SUM of P,C,A records matches the SUM of T records, it's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that "CORRECT" and "INCORRECT" are determined by comparing the "PCA" value to the "T" value, the following awk script should do the trick:

```
awk -F, -vOFS=, '$2=="T"{t[$1]+=$3;n[$1]} $2!="T"{s[$1]+=$3;n[$1]} END{ for(i in n){print i,"PCA",s[i]; print i,"T",t[i],(t[i]==s[i] ? "CORRECT" : "INCORRECT")} }' inputfile
```

Broken out for easier reading, here's what this looks like:

```
awk -F, -vOFS=, '

  $2=="T" {    # match all records that are "T"
    t[$1]+=$3  # add the value for this record to an array of totals
    n[$1]      # record this name in our authoritative name list
  }

  $2!="T" {    # match all records that are NOT "T"
    s[$1]+=$3  # add the value for this record to an array of sums
    n[$1]      # record this name too
  }

  END {        # Now that we've collected data, analyse the results
    for (i in n) {  # step through our authoritative list of names
      print i,"PCA",s[i]
      print i,"T",t[i],(t[i]==s[i] ? "CORRECT" : "INCORRECT")
    }
  }

' inputfile
```

Note that array order is not guaranteed in awk, so your output may not come out in the same order as your input.

If you want your output to be delimited using vertical bars, change the `-vOFS=,` to `-vOFS='|'`.

Then you can sort using:

```
awk ... | sort
```

which defaults to `-k1`.

Comment: That did it! I just have to add another condition to ignore the header and in cases that instead of "john", the record is "john p.", but that it's exactly what i nedd. thanks a lot.

Comment: Quick question: I'm trying now to use -vOFS='|' but it's not working... is there another way to define the demiliter?

Answer (score 1):

Awk is stream oriented. It processes input and outputs what you change. It does not do in file changes.

You just need to add a corresponding print

```
awk '{if($2 == "T") {print "MATCHED"}}'
```

If you want to output more than the "matched" you need to add it to the print
e.g. `'{print $1 "|" $2 "|"  $3 "|" " MATCHED"}'`

or use `print $0` as comment mentions above.